# How can we send Spring-xd shell commands from Batch Job

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-xd

Im trying to relaunch a JobB by running JobA. I was trying to use jobOperater.restart() and I was unsuccessful. I was able to restart the jobB from the xd-shell by "job execution restart --id 0". Can i do something similar by calling that command from JobA. Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `spring-xd-rest-client` jar has a `SpringXDTemplate`...

```
xdTemplate.jobOperations().restartJobExecution(jobId)
```

Comment: Will this be able to resume the job from the point of failure or from the point where the server goes down.?

For Example if we have 1000 rows to be processed, and failure occurs at 500. I want to resume from 501.

Thank you :)

Comment: As long as the job is configured (and coded) to be restartable it will restart where it left off. Search the [reference manual table of contents](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/index.html) with your browser for `restart` and read sections such as this one [Making the `ItemReader` Restartable](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#restartableReader).

Comment: I will try that out.. But your previous comment helped me to restart the job successfully. Thanks a ton.